# How can I address path of uploaded file to BufferedReader?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, bufferedreader, readfile

excuse my ignorance I 'm new to the JSF and Primeface. I uploaded a file with Primeface and then ı need to read that. You can see my codes and then I will ask my question.

SEND.java  CLASS

```
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    try {
        File targetFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Fatih\\Desktop\\DONE PNS\\pns_text");
        InputStream inputStream =  event.getFile().getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(targetFolder,
                event.getFile().getFileName()));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

BUFFEREDREADERPNS.java CLASS

```
  private BufferedReader br = null;
  private String tokenString = "";


    //SETTERS GETTERS



    public void read(){
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(??????????????));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            tokenString  = tokenString + sCurrentLine;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

send.xhtml file

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
fileUploadListener="#{send.handleFileUpload}"
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/"
auto="true" />
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

</h:form>


<p:commandButton  actionListener="#{bufferedReaderPNS.read}" action="send" 
value="Send" ajax="false" />
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can address the file that I uploaded. In BUFFEREDREADERPNS.java class in read() method  what I need to write in question mark? I wish I can tell my problem clearly, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Just use the same path/filename as you used in `new FileOutputStream()`? What exactly is your problem? That you are not storing the save path anywhere for future reference? This is hardly a JSF/PrimeFaces problem, but more basic Java.

Comment: @BalusC thank you  very much, it worked, now my problem is that when I uploaded a text file and used that I can see the information text files before I just uploaded. How can I delete or handle that?